# How to add visual effect in a frame with \framebreak

Tags: beamer, allowframebreaks

I want to apply visual effects to my slide so texts are shown while I press next (i.e. text shown on next slide) not just at once. 
I split my work into sections and then I understand the visual effect does work in a frame where `\framebreak` is used, only the first item in itemize appears.

This works well in a new frame, however. Is there a way to make it work in the frame I used `\framebreak`. This section contains lots of points I want to show, so I want the slides' title to be the same, auto-numbered.

I show an MSE of the scenario I explained below.
\documentclass{beamer}

```
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title[]{My presentation title}
\author[]{ My name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

\section{Previous Studies}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Literature-Some works}
    \blindtext

    \framebreak
    \textbf{visual effect doesn't work here, this frame uses the framebreak to add more slides}
    \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> \textbf{item-1} \\
                - some points 
            \item<2-> \textbf{item-2} \\
                - some more points
            \item<3-> \textbf{item-3} \\
                - some yet even more points
        \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{New frame -visual effect work here}
        \textbf{but visual effect works here, as you can see}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> \textbf{item-1} \\
                - some points 
            \item<2-> \textbf{item-2} \\
                - some more points
            \item<3-> \textbf{item-3} \\
                - some yet even more points
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```